# Extract Xpath from multiple different web addresses to excel file with python

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to expedite python code to extract a supermarkets website's Xpath (store opening and closing hours) to excel file. The code I use works, however it requires adding additional lines of code including new web address and line identifiers.

I have a text file with all the web addresses that need to be visited and the Xpaths are the same so far for each web address. Can python read any file list of web addresses extract the Xpath (store hours) and output to excel file without writing many lines of code?

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

def s1():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Me/Documents/PY/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://local.albertsons.com/mt/belgrade/6999-jackrabbit- 
    ln.html")
    time.sleep(2)
    a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
    [@id="mainStoreHours"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]').text
    b = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
    [@id="mainStoreHours"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[3]').text
    time.sleep(1)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Open Time' :a, 'Close Time' :b}, index=[9])
    driver.close()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Me/Documents/PY/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://local.albertsons.com/mt/bozeman/200-s-23rd-ave.html")
    time.sleep(2)
    c = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
    [@id="mainStoreHours"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]').text
    d = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
    [@id="mainStoreHours"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[3]').text
    time.sleep(1)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Open Time' :c, 'Close Time' :d}, index=[6])
    driver.close()
    df_all = pd.concat([df, df1])
    df_all.to_excel('Storehours.xlsx')
```

Comment: There's no need to open and close the browser for each site. Just reuse the browser to make it go faster. If you wanted it to go really fast, you could write it threaded where each run opens it's own browser, scrapes data, and closes but your current code isn't threaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that out:

```
import csv
import time

from selenium import webdriver


def make_action(url, b1, b2):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    a = driver.find_element_by_xpath(b1).text
    b = driver.find_element_by_xpath(b2).text
    return url, a, b

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
with open('file_pages.txt', newline='\n') as csvfile, open('new_file.csv', 'w+', newline='\n') as new_f:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    next(spamreader)
    file = csv.writer(new_f, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        file.writerow(make_action(*row))

driver.quit()
```

where file_pages.txt file should look like that:

```
url,b1,b2
https://local.albertsons.com/mt/belgrade/6999-jackrabbit-ln.html,//*[@id="mainStoreHours"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1],//span[@class='c-hours-details-row-intervals-instance-close'][1]
https://local.albertsons.com/mt/belgrade/6999-jackrabbit-ln.html,//*[@id="mainStoreHours"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1],//span[@class='c-hours-details-row-intervals-instance-close'][1]
```

where url is url, b1 - button or element1, b2 - button or element2

by the way, my advice, use webdriver-manager package:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

the code then looks like that, but you should not worry about chromedriver anymore it will download and replace without you, really convenient:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: OP said that the XPaths are always the same so no need to store those in the CSV. Your output is also not in the same format as OP's code.

Comment: Exchange `time.sleep(1)` with a proper `WebDriverWait` for the first element. There's also no need to open and close a new driver each loop. I know it's what OP did but it's not necessary. That would make sense if it were running as separate threaded tests but this isn't threaded.

Comment: Also your second URL is a duplicate of the first and not what OP had in their code.

Comment: @JeffC haven't noticed about the same xpaths, as for the WebDriverWait, there's quick solution, might you suggest using page object here?and duplicate url shows, that it's universal solution. Where you can use it for different sites.yes, driver can be opened once and moved to different browser just with get, good catch